# JMS Outbound Gateway on a clustered environment

Tags: spring-integration

We would be deploying Spring integration code to a web application running on a multiple tomcat servers. We have a JMS Outbound gateway like below. The question is whether it is possible that the message sent by one of the servlet container JVM (say tomcat1) can be received by another servlet container JVM (say tomcat2)? In our case, in the spring integration flow, we are splitting the message into multiple messages and sending it to JMS Outbound Gateway and once the response are received, we would be using aggregating the message back on the same JVM.

So it would become a problem if the response is received by other JVM. Does anyone know about this?

```
<int-jms:outbound-gateway id="wldpJMSGateway"
connection-factory="cachedConnectionFactory"
extract-reply-payload="true"
request-channel="wldpJMSGatewayChannel"
request-destination-name="WLDP.REQUEST.QUEUE"
reply-channel="wldpJMSResponseChannel"
reply-destination-name="WLDP.RESPONSE.QUEUE"
receive-timeout="5000"
extract-request-payload="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replies will go back to the correct gateway; a message selector is used.

**EDIT**

It's not documented in any detail (although it's hinted at in the discussion about `correlation-key` in the [gateway attributes section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html#jms-og-attributes)) but rest assured that the replies only go to the originating gateway. The actual mechanism depends on configuration.

For your configuration, the message selector is based on the outgoing `JMSMessageID`...

```
String messageSelector = "JMSCorrelationID = '" + messageId + "'";
```

... which is uniquely allocated by the JMS client library. This relies on the receiver copying the message id to the correlation id (which is a common pattern and is implemented by the SI inbound gateway as well as Spring JMS `MessageListenerAdapter`).

Setting the `correlation-key` to `JMSCorrelationID` will tell the gateway to use that instead, in which case, it is set to a generated value and...

```
messageSelector = "JMSCorrelationID = '" + correlationId + "'";
```

...this relies on the receiver echoing back the correlation id (which is again the usual pattern).

If there is a `<reply-listener/>` and a `correlation-key` the correlation id (and selector expression) includes a unique identifier for the gateway instance.

Finally, if no reply queue is defined, a temporary queue is used.

So, as you can see, we have thought of all possibilities to ensure the replies go to the right place.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see that it is documented here http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html. however it is not very clear that this would work even on a clustered environment. I am thinking that on a clustered environment, all the gateways (in different jvms) would be listening on the response queue. Are you suggesting that gateways have some mechanism to detect if the message originated from the same jvm else don't consume the message? If you could guide me to some documentation, I can read through that.

Comment: Thank you so much Gary for more explanation and confirming the behavior.